# How to use a rig

Tags: rigging

I am new to blender, and I was just wondering what I am doing wrong. I have downloaded a model to use in a game I'm making, and I don't seem to be able to control the rig that was downloaded alongside it. I have tried clicking on the individual things but nothing words. I have attached a picture of what it looks like.

Please don't downvote this post for being simple, it's just that I am new to blender and could really use someone's help.

Many thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: Do you have any knowledge at all about rigging

Answer (score 2):

That looks like a reasonable rig.  Provided that the downloaded version already has the rig parented to the model, you need to put Blender in *pose mode* before you can start moving the bones.  It looks like you already have the armature selected, so all you need to do is type CTRL-TAB.

Rigging and animation are fairly complicated topics, so I recommend that you go to youtube and follow one of the rigging tutorials there to learn more.  I personally think that *humane rigging* is a very good course for beginners, even though it is very old.

Answer (score 1):

You have access to your rig widgets if you switch from Object Mode to Pose Mode (drop-down menu in upper left corner). I can say for sure that your rig is a rigify rig. Rigify is a really powerful addon for blender (already as build-in). You need a little bit to know how to handle rigify rigs, especially that parts of your rig can be hidden or shown in the side panel on the right (if you press N, it shows up). As beginner it could be a little overwelming but if you get it how it works it's a pretty handy rig.